# Preg_match (REGEX) -- how to differentiate between accredited and credit?

Tags: php, regex

I find that my `preg_match` code is getting activated when `$_POST['subject']` has words like accredited, program, and happy. How can I tweak my Regex so that it prevent this from happening? I only want it to match the word credit or gram or app (case isn't important, hence the 'i') - not words that contain them.

```
if(preg_match("/credit|gram|app/i", $_POST['subject']))
```

Comment: Starting/ending anchors are your friend.  Or, if these are words in a longer string, space/word boundaries.

Comment: @chris Vastly expanded the explanation and including a second option.

Comment: Does `$_POST['subject']` contain multiple words or just one?

Comment: @chris I notice that you are fairly recent on the site and have not yet cast any vote. If you feel that someone's answer here solves your problem, please consider clicking on the left to accept it. There is no obligation to do so, but that is how reputation is acquired on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, in general, if you are trying to match an exact word, you need to add word boundaries around the word:

```
if(preg_match("/\bcredit\b|\bgram\b|\bapp\b/i", $_POST['subject']))
```

The boundary `\b` does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a "word character", and on the other side not.

This is only one of several way to ensure that you match entire words, but it is one of the easiest. For more complex situations, lookaheads and lookbehinds are often used.

Another option is the one mentioned by Joe: if in fact you are trying to match the entire string, then you can assert that by framing it between the start and end of string anchors `^` and `$`

This would give you:

```
if(preg_match("/^(?:credit|gram|app)$/i", $_POST['subject']))
```

Note that in between the `^` and the `$`, we have placed our alternation between parentheses. This ensures that whichever word is matched, it will be the entire string.

The `?:` at the beginning of the alternation is just there to indicate that the parentheses are non-capturing.